# How to print a list value one below another

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I need to sort a ranking of points by descending order. The users and points are inside `lista_ranking` which includes de following code:

[{'partido': {'codigo': 'AAA', 'fecha': datetime.date(2022, 11, 20), 'hora': '13:00hs', 'equipo_local': 'Catar', 'equipo_visitante': 'Ecuador', 'estado': 'Finalizado', 'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1}, 'usuario': {'cedula': '123', 'nombre': 'Gon', 'apellido': 'Henderson', 'fecha': '(2003, 3, 12)', 'puntaje': 5}, 'goles_local': 1, 'goles_visitante': 0}, {'partido': {'codigo': 'AAA', 'fecha': datetime.date(2022, 11, 20), 'hora': '13:00hs', 'equipo_local': 'Catar', 'equipo_visitante': 'Ecuador', 'estado': 'Finalizado', 'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1}, 'usuario': {'cedula': '1234', 'nombre': 'George', 'apellido': 'Stev', 'fecha': '(2003, 3, 12)', 'puntaje': 8}, 'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1}]

With the code

```
ranking_high_to_low=sorted([(numeros['usuario']['puntaje'], numeros['usuario']['nombre'], numeros['usuario']['apellido']) for numeros in lista_ranking], reverse=True) print(ranking_high_to_low)
```

It prints the ranking from highest to lowest like this:

```
[(8, 'George', 'Stev'), (5, 'Gon', 'Henderson')]
```

Which `for` should I use in order for it to print the ranking as follows:

```
George Stev 8
Gon Henderson 5
```

UPDATE:
@arsho
When I use your updated code:

```
def ranking():
ranking_high_to_low = sorted([(numeros['usuario']['puntaje'],
                           numeros['usuario']['nombre'],
                           numeros['usuario']['apellido']) for numeros in lista_ranking], reverse=True)

players = {}
for info in ranking_high_to_low:
    player_name = ' '.join(info[1:])
    players[player_name] = players.get(player_name, 0) + info[0]

for player, score in sorted(players.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(f"{player} {score}")
    for info in ranking_ordenado:
        print(f"{' '.join(info[1:])} {info[0]}")
```

The output of this is:

```
Juan Ha 8
Santi Stev 8
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Gon Va 20
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Santi Stev 16
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Gon Va 20
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Santi Stev 16
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Gon Va 20
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Santi Stev 16
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 16
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 20
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Santi Stev 16
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 16
Gon Va 10
Gon Va 10
Santi Stev 8
Santi Stev 8
Juan Ha 8
Juan Ha 8
```

Comment: This is not a `for` loop question.  If you have one record `a = (8, 'George', 'Stev')` how would you print `George Stev 8`? [PEP 498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to the solution. You can use a loop and join the part of the name to print the rank of the users.

```
import datetime

lista_ranking = [
    {'partido': {'codigo': 'AAA', 'fecha': datetime.date(2022, 11, 20),
                 'hora': '13:00hs', 'equipo_local': 'Catar',
                 'equipo_visitante': 'Ecuador', 'estado': 'Finalizado',
                 'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1},
     'usuario': {'cedula': '123', 'nombre': 'Gon',
                 'apellido': 'Henderson',
                 'fecha': '(2003, 3, 12)', 'puntaje': 5},
     'goles_local': 1,
     'goles_visitante': 0}, {
        'partido': {'codigo': 'AAA',
                    'fecha': datetime.date(2022, 11, 20),
                    'hora': '13:00hs', 'equipo_local': 'Catar',
                    'equipo_visitante': 'Ecuador',
                    'estado': 'Finalizado',
                    'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1},
        'usuario': {'cedula': '1234', 'nombre': 'George',
                    'apellido': 'Stev', 'fecha': '(2003, 3, 12)',
                    'puntaje': 8}, 'goles_local': 0,
        'goles_visitante': 1}]
ranking_high_to_low = sorted([(numeros['usuario']['puntaje'],
                               numeros['usuario']['nombre'],
                               numeros['usuario']['apellido']) for numeros in
                              lista_ranking], reverse=True)
for info in ranking_high_to_low:
    print(f"{' '.join(info[1:])} {info[0]}")
```

Output:

```
George Stev 8
Gon Henderson 5
```

The benefit of the `join` method here is how it can print the names with multiple parts (first name, middle name, last name).

**Update:**

If you want to store unique players and sort them by their total scores, you need to use a dictionary. Then sort the dictionary in reverse order by the scores.

```
import datetime

lista_ranking = [
    {'partido': {'codigo': 'AAA', 'fecha': datetime.date(2022, 11, 20),
                 'hora': '13:00hs', 'equipo_local': 'Catar',
                 'equipo_visitante': 'Ecuador', 'estado': 'Finalizado',
                 'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1},
     'usuario': {'cedula': '123', 'nombre': 'Gon',
                 'apellido': 'Henderson',
                 'fecha': '(2003, 3, 12)', 'puntaje': 5},
     'goles_local': 1,
     'goles_visitante': 0},
    {'partido': {'codigo': 'AAA', 'fecha': datetime.date(2022, 11, 20),
                 'hora': '13:00hs', 'equipo_local': 'Catar',
                 'equipo_visitante': 'Ecuador', 'estado': 'Finalizado',
                 'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1},
     'usuario': {'cedula': '123', 'nombre': 'Gon',
                 'apellido': 'Henderson',
                 'fecha': '(2003, 3, 12)', 'puntaje': 5},
     'goles_local': 1,
     'goles_visitante': 0}
    , {
        'partido': {'codigo': 'AAA',
                    'fecha': datetime.date(2022, 11, 20),
                    'hora': '13:00hs', 'equipo_local': 'Catar',
                    'equipo_visitante': 'Ecuador',
                    'estado': 'Finalizado',
                    'goles_local': 0, 'goles_visitante': 1},
        'usuario': {'cedula': '1234', 'nombre': 'George',
                    'apellido': 'Stev', 'fecha': '(2003, 3, 12)',
                    'puntaje': 8}, 'goles_local': 0,
        'goles_visitante': 1}]
ranking_high_to_low = [(numeros['usuario']['puntaje'],
                        numeros['usuario']['nombre'],
                        numeros['usuario']['apellido']) for numeros in
                       lista_ranking]

players = {}
for info in ranking_high_to_low:
    player_name = ' '.join(info[1:])
    players[player_name] = players.get(player_name, 0) + info[0]

for player, score in sorted(players.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(f"{player} {score}")
```

Output:

```
Gon Henderson 10
George Stev 8
```

**References:**

- [Blog article on ordering dictionary elements by values](https://arshovon.com/snippets/python-sort-dictionary/)

Comment: This worked! However when a user enters more than one game, instead of adding up the points, it prints the user with the added points but the amounts of times the user entered a game. As follows (one underneath each other but I don't know how to do it when commenting):
 
Gon Henderson 16
Gon Henderson 16
Gon Henderson 16
George Stev 8
George Stev 8

Comment: @PaniHardoy updated the code and explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: I just updated what my ouput is when I use your last update

Comment: @PaniHardoy can you insert the full updated code with the actual data to the question. Otherwise, we cannot debug it.

Comment: https://bpa.st/36AA 
Here is the full code. Is a program to predict the world cup games and depending the results of the games, how many points u get. The ranking is the last part on it

Comment: @PaniHardoy unfortunately this code is not printing anything as I assume `lista_ranking=[]`. StackOverflow suggests to include the shortest code and data in the question itself to reproduce the issue. I downloaded code from the external link, which I should not at the first place out of curiosity, but still cannot reproduce your issue. I think, you need to clean the question or ask a new question as it was initially just to print the values but now you are having issues with unique sum. This is not in scope of the original question. Help us to help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should do the trick:

```
   for (num, first, last) in ranking_high_to_low:
       print("{} {} {}".format(first, last, num))
```

Comment: This also worked! But happens the same thing, when a user enters more than one game, instead of adding up the points, it prints the user with the added points but the amounts of times the user entered a game. As follows (one underneath each other but I don't know how to do it when commenting): Gon Henderson 16 Gon Henderson 16 Gon Henderson 16 George Stev 8 George Stev 8